# Hibernate: Two relationships use the same column for their foreign keys

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, data-modeling

I am working on an application that needs to support a simple versioning system for a folder tree. In essence this means that a user can create a folder tree with different folders. When they are satisfied they can then save this version, create a new one and continue working on the new versions (much like a version control system if you will). My database schema looks like this currently:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS folder
(
    id           INT         NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    updated_at   TIMESTAMP   NOT NULL,
    created_at   TIMESTAMP   NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS folder_version
(
    id              INT          NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    version         INT          NOT NULL,
    folder_id       INT          NOT NULL,
    name            VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    updated_at      TIMESTAMP    NOT NULL,
    created_at      TIMESTAMP    NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE KEY (folder_id, version),
    FOREIGN KEY (folder_id) REFERENCES folder (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS folder_relation_version
(
    id         INT         NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    parent_id  INT         NOT NULL,
    child_id   INT         NOT NULL,
    version    INT         NOT NULL,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP   NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP   NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE KEY (parent_id, child_id, version),
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id, version) REFERENCES folder_version (folder_id, version),
    FOREIGN KEY (child_id, version) REFERENCES folder_version (folder_id, version)
);
```

However, I am unable to create an entity in Hibernate for the `folder_relation_version` table, since the `version` column is used in two foreign key constraints at the same time.

The specific design choice is actually intentional, because I want to avoid that two folder versions can be linked, when they are not part of the same version.

This means that the following scenario should be possible:
Folder_A (version=0) --> Folder_B (version=0)

But this scenario should not be possible:
Folder_A (version=0) --> Folder_B (version=1)

Below is my current attempt, which at least compiles, but obviously inserting and updating does not work with this approach:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@SuperBuilder
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@Entity
@Table(name = "folder_relation_version")
public class FolderRelationVersion extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "version")
    private Integer version;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", referencedColumnName = "folder_id", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "version", referencedColumnName = "version", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    private FolderVersion parent;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "child_id", referencedColumnName = "folder_id", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "version", referencedColumnName = "version", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    private FolderVersion child;
}
```

My question now is: Is there any way to model such a scenario in hibernate? Or is this just not the right way to make sure that a FolderVersion entities are linked only if they are part of the same version. Any hints, ideas or thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, for anyone who stumbles upon this issue too.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@SuperBuilder
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@Entity
@Table(name = "folder_relation_version")
public class FolderRelationVersion extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "version")
    private Integer version;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", referencedColumnName = "folder_id", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "version", referencedColumnName = "version", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    private FolderVersion parent;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "child_id", referencedColumnName = "folder_id", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "version", referencedColumnName = "version", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    private FolderVersion child;

    @Column(name = "child_id")
    private Integer childId;


    @Column(name = "parent_id")
    private Integer parentId;

    public void setChild(FolderVersion child) {
        this.child = child;
        this.childId = child.getFolderId();
    }

    public void setParent(FolderVersion parent) {
        this.child = parent;
        this.childId = parent.getFolderId();
    }
}
```

Apparently you just have to add the id fields explicitly and set them, whenever you set the entity, so that the database insert works.